# Why does not browser support unicode characters typed in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, browser, unicode

I am using netbeans 7.4 for PHP programming. I have a web form and need to insert a non-English language (Sinhalese)to the interface. I have installed various fonts of this language in my PC and my browser (firefox) renders these fonts properly, because I have viewed local websites using the browser.

Netbeans shows this font as squares and when I run it in the browser something like this à¶šà·œà·„à·œà¶¸à·à¶ºà·’is displayed. (Not squares). What is the reason for this? I really do not want to netbeans to show those characters. If the browser can render them, that would be enough.

Comment: Is your Netbeans account associated with FourSquare by accident?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a page character set problem?

Comment: @kerreSB - I don't have a netbeans account. What did you mean by this?

Comment: @Lexib0y - Yes, I think so, because I have visited different local sites which has this language and browser showed them without any problem.

Comment: could you provide a link to the page?

Comment: @Lexib0y - Highly appreciate your support. :). I found that not including meta tag to accept UTF-8 was the problem. I have posted it as the answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: I did not notice that is was your own answer, and that this was indeed the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question :)**

If you want to display unicode in your browser, you have to include below meta  under `<head>` tag of your html part. Otherwise it won't render non-English content. This worked for me, but netbeans still shows squares for non-English context. I don't mind it since I am using non-english only for user interfaces

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Hope this will help a future reader